# Cannot Create Glue Connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I setup a JDBC connection in AWS Glue to an RDS database. When I test the connection from AWS Console, I get an error: Could not find S3 endpoint or NAT gateway for subnetId xxxx. Why does AWS Glue connection to RDS need S3 VPC Endpoint?

The RDS instance has a security group that is completely open to all IP addresses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know exactly what it is needed for, but my Glue connection to RDS started working only when I had created S3 endpoint.

1. VPC → Endpoints
2. Create S3 endpoint

   - Service category: AWS services
   - Service name: com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.s3
   - VPC: choose one that your RDS is associated with
   - Route tables: choose one that contain subnets for VPC

Comment: Thanks for the update. I recreated my RDS instance and glue jobs and it worked perfectly fine. As you mentioned, if your source and destination is an S3 bucket and you do not want to connect to that bucket via the internet route. In my case, there was no involvement of S3 and so I was confused.

Comment: Huge help here! In particular, the default s3 endpoint DOES NOT CONTAIN ROUTE TABLES and so even once you've created it you'll be unable to connect through glue. When I edited route tables, it allowed me to select the ones already in use by the VPC which was helpful.